# How to arrange mdframed side by side?

Tags: positioning, mdframed

How to arrange `mdframed` side by side, like

`mdframed1`      `mdframe2`

```
\begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=10pt]
 table 1
\end{mdframed}
\leavevmode
\hspace{2cm}
\begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=10pt]
 table 2
\end{mdframed}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Placing each `mdframed` environment inside a `minipage` of specific width works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed
\begin{document}
\noindent
\null\hfill%
\begin{minipage}{.4\linewidth}
  \begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=10pt]
    table 1
  \end{mdframed}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{2cm}
\begin{minipage}{.4\linewidth}
  \begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=10pt]
    table 2
  \end{mdframed}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill\null
\end{document}
```

Change `.4\linewidth` to your liking. The use of `\null\hfill` ... `\hfill\null` is to centre the `mdframe`s within the text block without having to wrap it inside a group. `\centering` with a group would also work.

Comment: Great it works.

Comment: @Werner: as far as I tested, your solution does not manage correctly a mdframe spanning over multiple pages. I guess that the initial reason to use a mdframe would be to support multi-pages.
I did not find any solution yet.