# How to place side by side the same frame contents two times in landscape?

Tags: mdframed

Here is code for a single frame. I want the same page number contents to be printed in side by side. Here I am showing only a single page, sample as in figure.

```
    \documentclass[12pt,english,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{calligra}
    \usepackage[bottom=1.0cm,top=1.0cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,]{geometry}

    \usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \mdfdefinestyle{MyFrame}{%
        linecolor=black,
        outerlinewidth=2pt,
        roundcorner=20pt,
        innertopmargin=\baselineskip,
        innerbottommargin=\baselineskip,
        innerrightmargin=20pt,
        innerleftmargin=20pt,
        backgroundcolor=white,
        everyline=true }


    \newcommand*{\ClipSep}{1.4cm}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{isodate}
    \usepackage{datatool,filecontents}

    \centering

    \usepackage{titlecaps, stringstrings}


    \newcommand{\cname}[1][]{\bfseries  #1}
    \newcommand{\speaker}[1][Type author name]{{\bfseries Speaker:} \author{#1}}
    \newcommand{\theme}[1][]{{\bf Theme:} \it #1}
    \thispagestyle{empty}


    \begin{filecontents*}{event.csv}
        Time, Event
        08:00-08:30 am, Praise \& Worship
        08:30-10:00 am, Session - I (Live life to the fullest)
        10:00-10:15 am, Tea Break
        10:15-11:45 am, Session - II (Christian Giving)
        11:45-12:30 pm, Games
        12:30-01:30 pm, Lunch \& Rest
        01:30-03:00 pm, Session - III (Love \& Marriage)
        03:00 pm~~~~~~,"Vote of Thanks by Mr. xyz, YD"
    \end{filecontents*}

    \begin{filecontents*}{info.csv}
        ChurchName,MinistryName,SeminarName,Speaker,SpeakerOccupation,SpeakerAssociation, EventDate, Theme
        ABC church, youth ministry,oNe Day SemiNAr,Mr. XYZ,Mission Secretary,GDFS,2017-05-12,Live life to the fullest
    \end{filecontents*}
    \DTLloaddb{name}{event.csv}
    \DTLloaddb{information}{info.csv}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{mdframed}[style=MyFrame]
    \vspace*{4mm}
    \begin{center}
    \DTLforeach{information}{\church=ChurchName,\ministry=MinistryName,\seminar=SeminarName,\sp=Speaker,\oc=SpeakerOccupation,\sac=SpeakerAssociation, \evdate=EventDate, \thname=Theme}{
    \fontsize{35}{35}\selectfont
    %%%====== Changing Church Name starts here ==================
    \cname{\MakeUppercase{\church}}\\  %% Type here your church name
    %%%====== Changing Church Name end's here =====================
    %%%====== Changing Church Minstry Name starts here ==================
    \cname{\MakeUppercase{\ministry}}\\  %% Type here your church name
    %%%====== Changing Church Ministry Name end's here =====================

    \vspace{6mm}

    %%%====== Seminar types starts here ==================
    \caselower[q]{\seminar} 
    {\it\expandafter\titlecap\expandafter{\thestring}}
    %%%====== Seminar types end's here =====================



    \vspace{8mm}

    %%%====== Speaker name starts here ==================
    \speaker{\sp}\\  %% Type speaker name here
    %%%====== Speaker name end's here ==================
    \vspace{-4.0mm}
    %%%====== Speaker occupation and association starts here ==================
    \hspace*{30mm}{\Large (\oc, \MakeUppercase{\sac})}\\ %% Type Occupation and Association
    %%%====== Speaker occupation and association end's here ==================
    \vspace{6mm}

    \selectlanguage{english}
    %%%====== Event date starts here ==================
    \printdate{\evdate}\\ %% Type here date of events to be held
    %%%====== Event date end's here ==================
    \vspace{10mm}

    %%%====== Theme name starts here ==================
    \theme{\bfseries\thname}  %% Type here name of the theme
    %%%====== Theme name end's here ==================
    }
    \fontsize{18}{18}\selectfont %% default is 20 by 20
    \vspace{13mm}

    \begin{itemize}
    \DTLforeach{name}{\time=Time, \event=Event}{

    \item {\bf \time:} \rm{\event}\\
    \vspace*{3mm}
    }
    \end{itemize}

    \end{center}
    \end{mdframed}


    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am not familiar with `mdframed` and cannot test this at the moment but would [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50407/how-to-arrange-mdframed-side-by-side?rq=1) combined with [savebox](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes#savebox) do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `minipage`, but I should better swith to `tcolorbox` :

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[landscape,bottom=1.0cm,top=1.0cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,]{geometry}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\mdfdefinestyle{MyFrame}{%
  linecolor=black,
  outerlinewidth=2pt,
  roundcorner=20pt,
  innertopmargin=\baselineskip,
  innerbottommargin=\baselineskip,
  innerrightmargin=20pt,
  innerleftmargin=20pt,
  backgroundcolor=white,
  everyline=true }


\newcommand*{\ClipSep}{1.4cm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{isodate}
\usepackage{datatool,filecontents}

\centering

\usepackage{titlecaps, stringstrings}


\newcommand{\cname}[1][]{\bfseries  #1}
\newcommand{\speaker}[1][Type author name]{{\bfseries Speaker:} \author{#1}}
\newcommand{\theme}[1][]{{\bf Theme:} \it #1}
\thispagestyle{empty}


\begin{filecontents*}{event.csv}
  Time, Event
  08:00-08:30 am, Praise \& Worship
  08:30-10:00 am, Session - I (Live life to the fullest)
  10:00-10:15 am, Tea Break
  10:15-11:45 am, Session - II (Christian Giving)
  11:45-12:30 pm, Games
  12:30-01:30 pm, Lunch \& Rest
  01:30-03:00 pm, Session - III (Love \& Marriage)
  03:00 pm~~~~~~,"Vote of Thanks by Mr. xyz, YD"
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{info.csv}
  ChurchName,MinistryName,SeminarName,Speaker,SpeakerOccupation,SpeakerAssociation, EventDate, Theme
  ABC church, youth ministry,oNe Day SemiNAr,Mr. XYZ,Mission Secretary,GDFS,2017-05-12,Live life to the fullest
\end{filecontents*}
\DTLloaddb{name}{event.csv}
\DTLloaddb{information}{info.csv}

\begin{document}
\newsavebox{\mypicture}
\begin{lrbox}{\mypicture}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\linewidth}
    \begin{mdframed}[style=MyFrame]
      \vspace*{4mm}
    \begin{center}
      \DTLforeach{information}{\church=ChurchName,\ministry=MinistryName,\seminar=SeminarName,\sp=Speaker,\oc=SpeakerOccupation,\sac=SpeakerAssociation, \evdate=EventDate, \thname=Theme}{
        \fontsize{35}{35}\selectfont
        %%% ====== Changing Church Name starts here ==================
        \cname{\MakeUppercase{\church}}\\  %% Type here your church name
        %%% ====== Changing Church Name end's here =====================
        %%% ====== Changing Church Minstry Name starts here ==================
        \cname{\MakeUppercase{\ministry}}\\  %% Type here your church name
        %%% ====== Changing Church Ministry Name end's here =====================

        \vspace{6mm}

        %%% ====== Seminar types starts here ==================
        \caselower[q]{\seminar} 
        {\it\expandafter\titlecap\expandafter{\thestring}}
        %%% ====== Seminar types end's here =====================



        \vspace{8mm}

        %%% ====== Speaker name starts here ==================
        \speaker{\sp}\\  %% Type speaker name here
        %%% ====== Speaker name end's here ==================
        \vspace{-4.0mm}
        %%% ====== Speaker occupation and association starts here ==================
        \hspace*{30mm}{\Large (\oc, \MakeUppercase{\sac})}\\ %% Type Occupation and Association
        %%% ====== Speaker occupation and association end's here ==================
        \vspace{6mm}

        \selectlanguage{english}
        %%% ====== Event date starts here ==================
        \printdate{\evdate}\\ %% Type here date of events to be held
        %%% ====== Event date end's here ==================
        \vspace{10mm}

        %%% ====== Theme name starts here ==================
        \theme{\bfseries\thname}  %% Type here name of the theme
        %%% ====== Theme name end's here ==================
      }
      \fontsize{18}{18}\selectfont %% default is 20 by 20
      \vspace{13mm}

      \begin{itemize}
        \DTLforeach{name}{\time=Time, \event=Event}{

        \item {\bf \time:} \rm{\event}\\
          \vspace*{3mm}
        }
      \end{itemize}

    \end{center}
  \end{mdframed}
\end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}

 \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\linewidth}
   \usebox{\mypicture}
 \end{minipage}
 \hfill
 \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\linewidth}
   \usebox{\mypicture}
 \end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: page is not completely visible in the output @flav

Comment: @BikiTeron Yes I know, I can use for instance the `adjustbox` package but the best solution is to switch to `tcolorbox`